# Set Window Icon to Gtk Stock Icon in PyGtk

Tags: application-development, python, icons, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to add a Gtk stock icon to my window. Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='My Window Title')

        self.icon = self.render_icon(Gtk.STOCK_FLOPPY, 1)
        self.set_icon(self.icon)

        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

win = MyWindow()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

According to [this page](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--render-icon) icon size should be one of [Gtk icon size constants](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-constants.html#gtk-icon-size-constants)
but Eclipse code completion doesn't show any of the listed values and if I manually enter one of them I get

> AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR'

If I set the icon size to the literal 1 the script works. I'm sure this has to do something with Gtk or PyGtk versions, but I can't figure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance and sorry for the novice question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking at the PyGTK documentation, but are using PyGI/GTK3 in your script.

The docs on [`gtk_widget_render_icon()`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-render-icon) says the following:

> gtk_widget_render_icon has been deprecated since version 3.0 and should not be used in newly-written code. Use gtk_widget_render_icon_pixbuf() instead.

Then the docs on [`gtk_widget_render_icon_pixbuf()`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-render-icon-pixbuf) says this:

> gtk_widget_render_icon_pixbuf has been deprecated since version 3.10 and should not be used in newly-written code. Use gtk_icon_theme_load_icon() instead.

Great huh?! So let's move on.

[`gtk_icon_theme_load_icon()`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkIconTheme.html#gtk-icon-theme-load-icon) takes the following arguments:

- icon_name :  the name of the icon to lookup
- size :   the desired icon size. The resulting icon may not be exactly this size
- flags :  flags modifying the behavior of the icon lookup

Knowing this, you can change your old `render_icon` line with the following:

```
        icontheme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
        self.icon = icontheme.load_icon(Gtk.STOCK_FLOPPY, 128, 0)
```

Which will lookup a 128x128 px image. You might want to change the flags if needed, the enum is documented [here](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkIconTheme.html#GtkIconLookupFlags). This can be translated into Python like this:

```
GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_NO_SVG -> Gtk.IconLookupFlags.NO_SVG
GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_FORCE_SVG -> Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SVG
GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_USE_BUILTIN -> Gtk.IconLookupFlags.USE_BUILTIN
# And so on...
```